# Can't find .attr from jquery 'this' object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to find a data attribute from an html input in jquery.  Using 
    `$(this).attr("data-jsonid");` in the code below:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () 
        {
            if(!isNaN(this.name))
            {
                var currentId = $(this).attr("data-jsonid");

                if (currentId !== undefined)
                {
                    alert(currentId);
                }
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) 
                {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) 
                    {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
            return false;
```

I can see in my html source that all of my text inputs have a data-jsonid attribute, but I am unable to ever determine what it is in javascript/jquery.  I can only find the name and value when debugging.

I've created a jsfiddle project to aid in this explanation, http://jsfiddle.net/mvargos/dSz38/.  If you click "Submit Query" the json of the page is printed.  My end goal is that I want to be able to read the data-jsonid attribute so that I can format the way my json is saved if this attribute exists.
Currently the json is saved as

```
`{"1028":["Matt","Varg","27","2","Cris","Vargz","23","A"]}`
```

but once I can determine the data-jsonid, I would like to create the json similar to:

```
`"1028":[{"id":"1", "tenantInfo":["Matt","Varg","27","2"]},{"id":"2", "tenantInfo":["Cris","Vargz","23","A"]}]`
```

I am unsure if I am just doing something wrong syntax wise or making some other error.  Thank you for your help and please let me know if this explanation is poor.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can get `data-something` attributes simply as `$(selector).data('something')`.

Comment: What's the difference between your plugin and http://danheberden.com/jquery-plugin-serializeobject-2011-04-01/ ?

Comment: Nothing really, I was trying to modify the function that I found on a related post.

Comment: From my experience, it's exciting to reinvent the wheel sometimes, but this type of problem is so common there are probably dozens of libraries that do a much better job, and handle many use cases that have accumulated throughout their existence. So yeah, happy times, but know when to use a good plugin. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before serializing, you can 'remember' the jQuery version of `this`:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {

   var $this = $(this);

   ...
```

And then you can use $this, when you want to use it as a jQuery object.

```
   $this.data('some-data-attr');
```

Comment: The only downside is that `this` is the form, not each input.

Comment: @KevinB: I don't really see why that would be a downside. As long as it's a jQuery object, you can get to any parent or child node you need.

Comment: Although, admittedly, I would iterate the node tree and serialize bit by bit, possibly in a recursive function, rather than serializing the whole dang thing and then trying to figure out bits of the DOM from there.

Comment: Thank you for the help, your suggestion to iterate through the inputs instead of serializing the whole page makes more sense.  I was trying to reuse an example I found, but I don't think it will work in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = this.serializeArray();
```

The above line serializes the object ..

So basically you are iterating over the `array members` that are **not jquery Objects**

```
$.each(a, function ()
```

**$(this)** is not a proper selector in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't realize that I didn't actually have jquery objects at my disposal at that time.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in that context is not the input element, it's just a plain object. You'll have to navigate back to the input to get that information:

```
$("[name=" + this.name + "]").data("jsonid");
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to see exactly what was going on in my example, but I won't be able to use this solution since I have multiple inputs sharing the same name.